# Can I use the MySql CSV storage engine to capture the CSV in a php program

Tags: php, mysql

The MySQL CSV storage engine "creates a table format file in the database directory". Because of the nature of my application deployment I do not have access to the file system from my PHP program.

Is there a way to use the Csv Engine to have the csv file created either as a db table or in a text or blob column of an existing table?

I know that I can manually create csv entries row by row in my PHP program, however because of size and speed I'm trying to use the MySQL CSV engine.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL CSV engine is of no use to you here. (Arguably, it's of very little use to anybody.)

What it does is make MySQL store table data internally as a CSV file, instead of in its typical native InnoDB (or MyISAM) format. If you do not have access to the MySQL data directory -- which you don't appear to here -- this won't do you any good. All it'll do is make the table really slow, and prevent you from using indexes or NULL columns.

Use PHP to generate CSV output.